# Are virtual functions safe in real-time audio programming?

Tags: c++, audio, real-time

Real-time audio programming has particular constraints, due to the need to avoid audio glitches. Specifically, allocating and deallocating memory, or otherwise interacting with the operating system, should not be done in the audio thread.

When calling a virtual function, the program must find the relevant virtual table, lookup the pointer, and then call the function from the pointer. **Is this process real-time safe?**

Comment: The real question is what are your alternatives to implement the same functionality?

Comment: Too generic and too complex. In fact that you actually asking such a thing means you are not well prepared to deal with audio. Start with the basics.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis What would you consider the basics that I'm missing here? Do you know any resources so I can understand these things better and ask more helpful questions?

Comment: On the surface, the answer to this is "yes, virtual functions are fine in real-time audio." But be aware that if you, say, are calling several virtual functions per audio sample, you may be harming performance and optimizations. A liberal use of inheritance-based OOP with dynamic dispatch won't be as performant and efficient as a carefully data-driven approach, but that's a different and very broad topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  Virtual function dispatch is just like writing `(*(obj->vtable[5]))(obj, args...)`.  It doesn't involve any operations of unknown or possibly surprising complexity like allocating memory or I/O.

Answer (score 1):

A real-time system is not defined by the programming language, but rather the OS/hardware.

So long as the system is real-time, and the software executing is [deterministic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38152/what-is-determinism-in-computer-science#:%7E:text=A%20deterministic%20program%20would%20behave,same%20output%20will%20always%20occur.), you will have real-time performance. In regards to your question, the use of virtual functions does not violate determinism.

Another concern might be latency. The amount of latency that you might encounter will be determined by the OS, the hardware, and the software, but as Matt Timmermans mentioned in his answer, virtual functions cause little overhead and will not contribute significantly to latency.